Convert date text values from file to date time format in snowflake



LoadDate
Required Output




2021/07/30 00:00:00
2021-07-30 00:00:00


2020/03/06 00:00:00
2020-03-06 00:00:00


2024-May-23
2024-05-23 00:00:00


2020/06/26
2020-06-26 00:00:00



select TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(LOADDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS');

but failing with the error

Can't parse '2024-May-23' as timestamp with format 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'

Could someone help me please

You would need a separate statement for each of the different formats your data is in, use TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP in each statement and then combine them in something like a CASE or COALESCE statement

Why have you tagged SQL Server when your RDBMS is Snowflake?

I wanted reach this question to more wide techgeeks

Please refrain, knowledge of SQL Server doesn't help with a Snowflake problem - and you will just attract downvotes. No 2 RDBMS use the exact same SQL dialect.

BTW: Are you familiar with accepting an answer? It seems quite a while since you have done so.

so long winded example code:
select $1 as input,
    $2 as wanted,
    try_to_timestamp_ntz($1,'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi:ss') as ts_1,
    try_to_timestamp_ntz($1,'YYYY-Mon-DD') as ts_2,
    try_to_timestamp_ntz($1,'YYYY/MM/DD') as ts_3,
    coalesce(ts_1, ts_2, ts_3) as _result,
    to_char(_result, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') = wanted as happy
    
from values
    ('2021/07/30 00:00:00', '2021-07-30 00:00:00'),
    ('2020/03/06 00:00:00', '2020-03-06 00:00:00'),
    ('2024-May-23', '2024-05-23 00:00:00'),
    ('2020/06/26',  '2020-06-26 00:00:00');



What if i have the value like '2020/06/26 22:30' and i want to see it like '2020-06-26 22:30:00'

'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi' would seem to cover the external to internal convertion. The output is already solved.
